# In Cognito is there a way to log in from the perspective of a specific user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

To onboard users to our platform we'd like the marketing team to be able to use the application as if they were the user. So that everything can be set up ahead of time when it comes times for our demo/onboarding session.

Does Cognito support logging in with one account and gaining access to another? We are trying to avoid rolling our own authentication in front of Dynamo and just using what comes form Cognito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just implemented something very similar this week. Cognito doesn't really support it, no. But if you are already committed to Cognito, you can fudge it if you're accessing Cognito from a backend server. Basically you create a Custom Auth Flow.

If the account does not yet exist:

- Run AdminCreateAccount. Specify the temp password.
- Run AdminInitiateAuth. Sign in with the temp password. Set a new password.
- You have the user's tokens (i.e. you are signed in as them)

If the account already exists:

- Create a [Custom Auth Flow](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/customizing-your-user-pool-authentication-flow/). You basically need three seperate Lambdas. Each Lambda is called by the corresponding Cognito Triggers (DefineAuthChallenge, CreateAuthChallenge, VerifyAuthChallenge). Technically you can get away with just the first one if you simply choose the return tokens whenever DefineAuthChallenge is called).
- Call AdminInitiateAuth and specify the Custom Auth Flow. You can do more or less whatever you like here, like just authenticate anyone who is an admin to any other account. You get back the target user tokens, maybe you create a server session or return these to your frontend, it depends on your app.

That's quite an abridged version I know. As I say, possible, but unpleasant.

My use case was actually creating 'Magic Links', which when used, create and authenticate a user, as well as taking them to a specific page. This is invaluable in removing authentication flow friction (e.g. on marketing emails), but is not supported by Cognito Flows. I used the above technique to work around this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there isn't such a feature in Cognito.

A workaround is to manually set their password as an Administrator using the `AdminSetPassword` API call, and log-in to their account. However, that does not seen too plausible, and what you would require as mentioned in your question isn't directly supported by Amazon Cognito.

Comment: Thank you, I feared as much.